# Nexus 4 ubuntu touch - No internet connection while cellurar data only enabled

Tags: ubuntu-touch, internet

I have loaded ubuntu touch on my Nexus 4 and I don't seem to get the Internet to work while cellular data is enabled only. Wi-Fi works ok but as soon as I step outside the house and loose the wi-fi, I'm on my own..lol
I have loaded the latest developer build:
Carrier is T-Mobile USA.

```
root@ubuntu-phablet:~# system-image-cli -i
current build number: 203
device name: mako
channel: devel
alias: ubuntu-touch/utopic
last update: 2014-08-24 16:32:04
version version: 203
version ubuntu: 20140821.1
version device: 20140811.1
```

If anybody finds a way to get this working by all means help...!

Answer (score 1):

Took me a minute, but here you go:

```
cd /usr/share/ofono/scripts/
./deactivate-context
./set-context-property 0 Protocol ip
./activate-context
ifconig
```

`ifconfig` is just to verify you got an IP. The default protocol is set to ipv6 and doesn't jive with the t mobile network. Happy trails!

Now to get gps and navigation working..

Comment: Nice worked on my nexus 5 with one modification it seems `0` was in use so I set `./set-context-property 1 Protocol ip`